# Change in status of Lord Vishnu's wives according to Brahma vaivartha purana

Tags: puranas, goddess, curse

The Brahma Vaivarta Purana mentions the exchange of curses among the Goddesses - Lakshmi, Saraswathi & Ganga when they were wives of Lord Vishnu. Will they get back to their original positions after the curse is over? When will that be?

Comment: I don't know if this story is mentioned in Brahmavaivartara Purana but Devi Bhagavatam mentions it.

Comment: Story you mentioned happened in Devi Bhagavatam not in BvP. Do you want that story?

Comment: It is mentioned in both BVP & Devi Bhagavatam ( story ) Thank U .Got it.